FileNotFoundException concerning System.Diagnostics.EventLog DLL when starting the simplest possible Windows Service with .Net Core 8
I have already developed many Windows services in .NET 4.x, but this is the first time I use .NET Core 8.
Program.cs:
using MyService;

IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseWindowsService(options => {
        options.ServiceName = "MyService";
    })
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) => {
        services.AddHostedService<MyWorker>();
    })
    .Build();
await host.RunAsync();

MyWorker.cs:
namespace MyService;

public class MyWorker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<MyWorker> _logger;

    public MagSageWorker(ILogger<MyWorker> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            if (_logger.IsEnabled(LogLevel.Information))
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
            }
            await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}

Every time, I get this exception:

Application: MyService.exe
CoreCLR Version: 8.0.724.31311
.NET Version: 8.0.7
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.EventLog, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.
File name: 'System.Diagnostics.EventLog, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'
at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog.EventLogLogger..ctor(String name, EventLogSettings settings, IExternalScopeProvider externalScopeProvider)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog.EventLogLoggerProvider.CreateLogger(String name)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerInformation..ctor(ILoggerProvider provider, String category)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFactory.CreateLoggers(String categoryName)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFactory.CreateLogger(String categoryName)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger1..ctor(ILoggerFactory factory) at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor) at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeDirectByRefWithFewArgs(Object obj, Span1 copyOfArgs, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
at System.Reflection.MethodBaseInvoker.InvokeWithOneArg(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(ServiceIdentifier serviceIdentifier)
at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func2 valueFactory)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(ServiceIdentifier serviceIdentifier, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass35_0.b__2(IServiceProvider _)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(ServiceIdentifier serviceIdentifier)
at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func2 valueFactory)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(ServiceIdentifier serviceIdentifier, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.ResolveHost(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, DiagnosticListener diagnosticListener)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
at Program.$(String[] args) in C:\Users\MyUsername\source\repos\MySolution\MyService\Program.cs:line 4
at Program.(String[] args)

I tried a few solutions found online, but absolutely no difference:

Updating all dependencies
Adding System.Diagnostics.EventLog manually to the project
Placing System.Diagnostics.EventLog.dll in the binary folder
Forcing System.Diagnostics.EventLog version in .csproj file
etc.

I'm running out of clues to find the solution, so I need your help.
Thanks.

Edit 1:
MyService.csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <UserSecretsId>dotnet-MyService-guid-removed</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Json" Version="8.0.4" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>


Would you mind posting the .csproj just in case there's something there that catches someone's attention?

@NPras Done, but there's nothing special.

Did you also get the error when running under debug, or only when installed as a service?  Your code (which I assume is almost straight from the dotnet template) seems to work fine here. If you do a dotnet clean and rebuild, does it bring in the missing dll automatically to the bin folder? Also, open up MyService.deps.json in the bin folder, look for the entry for System.Diagnostics.EventLog.dll, and see if the fileVersion matches the actual dll file version.

It never adds the missing dll automatically, and even when I add it manually I have the same error. In MyService.deps.json it's the good 8.0.0.0 version.

Makes one wonder if there's a mismatch between the installed SDK, Runtime, and Visual Studio. Single-File Publish will bundle the runtime libraries. If you look at the output window when publishing, you'll see that it's pulling Runtime libraries from NuGet, instead of using the ones installed in the system - which may be why it works. Might be a long shot, but reinstalling both the SDK and Desktop Runtime may (or may not) make a difference.

Also, performing a build on VIsual Studio, and performing one from the cmdline with dotnet build can sometimes produce a different outcome. dotnet build MyApp --verbosity diag might show you something useful with regards to what is happening.

We were getting this error log when trying to start up the windows service after bundling it using Wix installer.
After struggling a bit we managed to get it working by publishing the project with the options self-contained and single file and running the generated exe.
profile settings
It does mention doing this in the Net tutorial but it is frustrating as the file size is bigger. So hopefully there is another suggestion to get around this.
You can then run the windows service using:
sc.exe create "NameOfService" binpath= "C:\Path\To\App.WindowsService.exe"

Something else that might be worth including (but not 100%) is a reference to the event log in your app settings file:
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    },
    "EventLog": {
      "SourceName": "SoftwareAgent.WindowsService",
      "LogName": "Application",
      "LogLevel": {
        "Microsoft": "Information",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
      }
    }
  }
}


I was already installing the service using sc.exe. Including a reference to the event log in the app settings does nothing, but it works when publishing the project with the options self-contained and single file. It isn't THE solution, but at least, for the moment I can continue coding. Thanks for that tip. I still wondering why it doesn't work when not in self-contained mode.

It worked well as a self-contained and single-file project, but now also without these two options simply by targetting x86 platform.
